# Firebase Storage security rule error- User does not have permission

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I am authenticating to firebase using **custom tokens**. I want to restrict only the current user to have access to write and delete the image and grant read access to everyone.

below code is part of my swift code related to storage

```
let filePath = REF_STORAGE.child("/"+(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!+"/profilepic.jpeg")
let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"
```

And my current firebase storage rule is as shown below

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/test-123456789.appspot.com/o {
    match /{uid}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

When i try to upload image i get the following error

***User does not have permission to access gs://test-123456789.appspot.com/MYAUTHUID/profilepic.jpeg.***

But if i change the storage rule to below storage rule, i am able to upload the image and the profilepic is stored under /gs://test-123456789.appspot.com/123456789/profilepic.jpeg

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/test-123456789.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Kindly let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't oversimplified your example? Because your provided rules are basically identical to https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security#full_example , and should therefor work.

Comment: @Dreamcooled. have been at this issue since morning still i havent figured out the solution

Comment: You forgot to answer my question

Comment: @Dreamcooled. Yes im pretty sure :)

Answer (score 2):

Does your `{uid}` contain any special characters? (e.g '+' sign)

**Note**: [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) replied to me that this issue is under investigation, following a bug report I sent them 3 days ago: I discovered that calling {userid} doesn't work for me in Firebase Storage Rules if it contains the '+' sign.

I use phone numbers in E.164 format (e.g: `"+97234567899"`).
I tried several run tests, and they clearly showed there's an issue with the value returned from {uid}:

1. `request.auth != null;` - *Worked*
2. `request.auth.uid != null;` - *Worked*
3. `request.auth.uid == "+97234567899";` - *Worked*
4. `request.auth.uid == uid;` - ***Didn't work***

However, I found a way to bypass this issue. This is what I came up with:

---

**Solution**

```
resource.name.split('/')[position]
```

Since {uid} represents a folder name, you can extract its value by manipulating the full path string of the file using `resource.name`, splitting it by ('/') and then selecting the relevant hierarchy.

For example: if this is your path: `/Images/Profiles/{uid}/profile.jpg`, then extract the uid like this: `resource.name.split('/')[2]`

In your code sample, I would do this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/test-123456789.appspot.com/o {
    match /{uid}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.name.split('/')[0];
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Edit** (July 28th, 2017)

Firebase Support has replied to my report a month ago, and the issue has been identified & now being taken care of.

However, in the meantime, if you wished to authenticate by phone number (like I did) - we shouldn't be using Custom Tokens anymore, because Firebase now supports such authentication.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still having this problem: Updating your firebase security rules to the following did the trick for me.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```